# add new axis to highcharts dynamically, on selection from dropdown

Tags: jquery, highcharts

i am trying to draw highcharts for cpu parameter, disk parameter, memory parameter. i can click on dropdown to select particular parameter. my task is to draw highcharrts when i click on a particular parameter . i want to keep the previous graph drawn. that is to say, i want to add graph on selection of any parameter from dropdown.
i have written following code

```
function DrawTrendCpu(plot,TypeOfParameter,sub_type) {
    itemdata=[];

    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Server Monitroting Tool'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text:  TypeOfParameter+'   usage'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                categories: ['TIME']
            },
            yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.value +'%';
                    },
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: "core " +sub_type,
                    style: {
                        color: '#89A54E'
                    }
                }
            }],
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                x: 120,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 80,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            series: []
        });
    });

    if (TypeOfParameter=='memory')
    {
        for (i = 0; i< plot.length; i++) {
            x = parseFloat(plot[i][3]);
            itemdata.push((x));
        }

        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall'
            },
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#08F',
            opposite: true
        });
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'memory',
            type: 'spline',
            color: '#08F',
            yAxis: "memory usage ",
            data: itemdata
        });
    }
    else if(TypeOfParameter=='cpu')
    {
        console.log("cpu")
        //console.log(plot["all"])

        console.log(plot[0].length,"hey")
        for (i = 0; i< plot[0].length; i++) {
            itemdata.push(parseFloat(plot[i][8]));
        }

        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.addSeries({
            name: "core "+sub_type,
            data: itemdata
        }, false);
        chart.redraw();
    }
    else if (TypeOfParameter=='disk')
    {
        for (i = 0; i< plot.length; i++) {
            x = parseFloat(plot[i][3]);
            itemdata.push((x));
        }
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.addSeries({
            name: "disk "+sub_type,
            data: itemdata
        },false);
        chart.redraw();
    } 
}
```

what i am trying to do is add extra axes dynamically,but is is giving me error 18, some help please. i am newbie .

Answer (score 0):

```
        chart.addAxis({ // Secondary yAxis

            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall'
            },
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: '#08F',
            opposite: true
        });
        chart.addSeries({
            name: 'memory',
            type: 'spline',
            color: '#08F',
            **yAxis: "memory usage ",**
            data: itemdata
        });
```

Looking at this code.  You are adding an Axis, but you are not setting the id and then you try to access the yAxis by id in the addSeries call.  So, either access the yAxis by number or add an id to your Axis definition.